# Can normalization decrease model performance of ensemble methods?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, normalization

Normalization e.g. z-scoring is a common preprocessing method in Machine Learning. I am analyzing a dataset and use ensemble methods like Random Forests or the XGBOOST framework.

Now I compare models using

1. non normalized features
2. z-scored features

Using crossvalidation I observe in both cases that with higher max_depth parameter the training error decreases.

For the 1. case the test error also decreases and saturates at a certain MAE:

[image]

For the z-scored features however the test error is non-decreasing at all.

[image]

In the question [Would you recommend feature normalization when using boosting trees?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16225/would-you-recommend-feature-normalization-when-using-boosting-trees)  was discussed that normalization is not necessary for tree based methods. But the example above shows that it has a severe effect.

So I have two questions regarding this:

- Does it imply that overfitting with ensemble based methods is possible even when the test error decreases?
- Should normalization like z-scoring always be common practice when working with ensemble methods?
- Is it possible that normalization methods decrease the model performance?